# No module named urllib3 but it is installed

Tags: python, python-2.7, anaconda, virtualenv

i am using python version

> Python 2.7.13 :: Anaconda custom (64-bit)

when i am trying to create virtual environment by

```
virtualenv venv
```

it shows error :

```
New python executable in /home/k/Desktop/heroku/pincode2/venv/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...
  Complete output from command /home/k/Desktop/hero...ode2/venv/bin/python - setuptools pip wheel:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 7, in <module>
  File "/home/k/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
  File "/home/k/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_vendor/requests/__init__.py", line 62, in <module>
  File "/home/k/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
ImportError: No module named urllib3
----------------------------------------
...Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/k/anaconda2/bin/virtualenv", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/k/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 713, in main
    symlink=options.symlink)
  File "/home/k/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 945, in create_environment
    download=download,
  File "/home/k/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 901, in install_wheel
    call_subprocess(cmd, show_stdout=False, extra_env=env, stdin=SCRIPT)
  File "/home/k/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 797, in call_subprocess
    % (cmd_desc, proc.returncode))
OSError: Command /home/k/Desktop/hero...ode2/venv/bin/python - setuptools pip wheel failed with error code 1
```

but urllib3 is already installed. Any help? please .

Comment: Could you make sure of that? :)
`pip freeze | grep -i urllib3`

Comment: Yes, it shows 'urllib3==1.22'

Comment: and if you ask for `conda list` it also shows up? If so, I'll be lost in thought for a while..

Comment: it shows 'urllib3   1.16    <pip>' and  'urllib3 1.22  <pip>'

Comment: 2 versions of urllib? Uff..That is a different matter; let me just ignore that for now.
The issue probably has little to do with urllib itself. There are 2 things I can think of: your system path points towards your OS installation of Python instead of your custom installation and you have an old pc. The other is somehow something goes wrong when linking to another package like `openssl`, which is referenced in the `__init__` of urllib3. In which case probably the python packages installed need to be updated.

Comment: So what should i do ? Can a website be deployed in heroku without virtualenv

Comment: Why are you using virtualenv with conda? You should not mix conda and virtualenv, you should use conda environments